# Guild Members filter not Accurate

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I've been trying to make a counter which obviously counts the members of the server without the bots, with the bots, and only the bots and for some reason, it's not accurate what so ever. When I get into the general channel and run the command to display the counter, I get these as the output numbers:

Code:

```js
const memberCount = message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size;
const totalCount = message.guild.memberCount;
const botCount = message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.user.bot).size;
```

Output on a server with 20 Members:

```
1st Output is: 1
2nd Output is: 19 (It excludes itself for some reason? but i can fix that with just +1)
3rd Output is: 1
```

Clearly there is an issue with the code but I can't pinpoint what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try fetching the members instead of reading them from the `.cache`.

```js
const members = await message.guild.members.fetch();
const memberCount = members.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size;
const botCount = members.filter(member => member.user.bot).size;
const totalCount = members.size;
```

If you are on discord.js v13, make sure you have `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent enabled.

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "GUILD_MEMBERS"] });
```

Note that if you want to cache the members automatically on bot's startup, you need to enable `GUILD_PRESENCES` intent. Otherwise when `GUILD_CREATE` event is emitted on the websocket for the bot to cache guilds, members and users. The data won't include any `GuildMember`s except the bot itself. (That is why it shows you the number `1`.)

<sub>Tested using discord.js `^13.0.1`.</sub>

Comment: Works perfectly, and I'm using Discord.js V12 Because I find the whole intents thing dumb tbh

Comment: Glad to hear that! Yep, it is a bit annoying... But you can always enable all the intents and don't care.

Comment: I'm actually getting issues with the bot where where it prints ``Null``

Comment: What do you mean, is this related to my answer?

Comment: Yeah, i think its from my end though because i tried to decrement the total users from the users and still Null, its causes issues at a certain step, so im testing fixes right now